# Creating multiple Gmail Accounts

Tags: email, gmail, testing, google, accounts

To check my application in a software testing environment , prior to launch where it requires the mail sending functionality to different email and in order to check multiple scenarios, i need to create at least 25 e-mail accounts.

So i thought of using Gmail .But however creating 25 accounts looks hectic.Does Gmail have any functionality that would support my requirement, or can anybody suggest a smart work that would saves my  time.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/) account for your domain then creating 25 email adresses under that domain ?

Comment: Its a new dimension of thought for me, thanks.After creating a google apps using my company domain, will i be able to scrap it away?.I would be able to use the domain name as it is for testing in a limited period.

Comment: Yes definently all you have to do is delete MX records. You must use a domain not currently having a mail server.

Comment: Do you have any idea on the free domain providers probably with a limited validity? So that i can check my tests by creating a google apps.It would hardly take me a week to complete test.

Comment: You. Just use a subdomain of your main domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single account and use + addressing to keep track of your scenarios.  See here:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

Comment: I have tried sending to the same gmail account as it was detailed like xxx@gmail.com,xxx+p1@gmail.com,xxx+p2@gmail.com.But when i logged in to the xxx@gmail.com only one mail was there.Did i understand the link in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

If you own a domain name, then setup a catchall- which then delivers all the emails to the same address. eg, anything@somedomain.com would then deliver to yourgmail@gmail.com. This should be quite easy to do.